# Google Sheets batch rename files with a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, rename

I have a lot of numbers in my sheet and I would like to rename over 100 different files. Example, the number in my sheet with the number 1 I want to rename it to 01.png. I`ve tried already the search and replace function, but it is very time consuming, if I want to do it multiple times on x sheets... Gives here a better and quicker solution?

I've tried already the replace function:

```
=REPLACE(A1;1;3;"_01.PNG")
```

It gives me the right output file name, but I have to select thousands of a number 1.
How can I select all Number 1 (formatted in text) and set this function?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a programmer's question and answer site. We do not accept free code requests. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/ for the type of questions, you're expected to ask here.

Comment: Kindly show us what you've tried and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT:

Try this:

```
function rename() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,sheet.getLastColumn()); //this will automatically select all data in your active sheet starting from row 2
  var data = range.getValues(); //get the values, this will return 2D array

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++){
      data[i][j] = "_" + pad(data[i][j]) + ".PNG" //replace each data with "_NUMBER.PNG"
    }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
}

function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
```

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Thank you, but I need it for all columns in the sheets. How can I set this? Select another column, was no problem for me, but how can I select all?

Comment: @sreeze - See my updated answer. Also kindly refrain from using answer to add information to your post. You can always update your post by using the edit button.

Answer (score 0):

Customized Code, it only changed me the names from the first column (A). What I have to change here? Thanks.

```js
function rename() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets(); 
  
  sh.forEach(sheet => { 
    var range = sheet.getRange("A2:F301"); //get all the cells from my sheet
    var data = range.getValues(); 
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
      data[i][0] = "_" + pad(data[i][0]) + ".PNG" //replace each data with "_NUMBER.PNG"
    }
    range.setValues(data); 
  })

}

function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).